# drupal add video Video Embed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I will Try to add Video Embed to drupal-7 programmatically
with thumb. 
This is what I've tried:

```
$url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zq3KCBed5Q';
$file_path = drupal_realpath($url);
$file->uid = 1;
$file->filename = 'dsdss';
$file->uri = $url;
$file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($file_path);
$file->type = 'video';
$file->status = 1;
$file_exists = file_save($file); 
$node->field_videoyou[$node->language]['0'] = (array) $file_exists;
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, drupal_realpath is converting local drupal path to absolute path and you are passing to it absolute path. Also, you didn't show us where you create that $file object. What is that?

If you check file_save() docs:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7

...you'll see that $file should be "a file object returned by file_load()."

So, I think that you are using drupal_realpath wrong, don't see that you are using file_load() for creating $file object and I don't see that you are copy-ing file to your server.

My suggestion is not to mess with files anyway, but just take player embed code and use it. You can have some text field to your content type where admin can insert video embed code and just shoot that value out on front-end.
Moreever...it will probably happen that embed code is pretty similar for different videos and that only difference is just some video id value so you don't even have to store whole embed code, but just that video id and you can keep rest of embed code in some template file, as static, where you will just insert video id.

Comment: hi MalanG if you can help me

Comment: hi MalanG if you can help me we have old web site with database and we create new site with drupal
 I need to add node programmatically from old database I success but IF Node have video embed field is failed 
Machine Name                     FIELDTYPE                    WIDGET 

TITLE                                
BODY 
Field_videoyou                  video embed                 video

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question. When you create some field you can choose it's machine name on your own. It will just automatically get "field_" prefix.